# Float looks different in IE 7 and IE 8 (html validated)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, css-float

Hello I am trying to understand differences in the rendering of this page in Chrome (the target) and IE 7/8:

```
http://phor.net/PRIV/md2/ (it validates)
```

In IE 7, the top navbar does not float the LIs and in IE 8, there's a hideous margin at the top.

This page is very simple, with all style in

```
http://phor.net/PRIV/md2/style.css
```

**Any idea on how to fix that navbar?** Thank for your help and discussion.

Comment: You will forever have issues with IE and trying to make it work like the other far more modern browsers, no matter which version of IE it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 does not fully support the inline-block property that you are using on your navigation bar.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Try using floats instead.

```
#navbar ul li { float: left; }
```

Make sure you clear your floats afterward.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 doesn't support `inline-table`, you could use `float: left;` or `display: inline;`.

Sorry, don't see any huge margin in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

use `float:left` property instead of `display:inline-table`

Change this

```
#navbar li {
font: 14px Arial;
margin: 0;
margin-right: -2em;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-table;
}
```

to

```
#navbar li {
font: 14px Arial;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
float:left;
Padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#navbar li { display:block; float:left; width:160px;}
#navbar ul { overflow:hidden;}
```

and remove all `display:inline-table`

I make an example for you

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ525/3/)